# Stop the Windows accessibility narrator from reading WPF XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, accessibility

By default the Windows accessibility narrator reads out loud any WPF controls it finds. If a control doesn't have a label or automation property the narrator reads all the XAML/XML properties instead.

This works properly:

`<Button AutomationProperties.Name="Read me" Width="100" Height="20"/>`

The narrator will read out the width and height on this button:

`<Button Width="100" Height="20"/>`

Is there any way to disable the reading of non-visible properties or set the narrator to only read controls with names?

Comment: I don't recall running into that, which reader are you using?

Comment: The standard windows narrator (Windows 10)

Comment: Looks like I got something new to learn too then. +1

Comment: facing similar issue.any pointers?

Comment: This is killing my performance. As soon accessibility.dll loads up, it does hundreds of thousands of equality checks per second. And it loads up as soon as a tooltip or menu item pops up.